# More generic live preview editor? (can support pandoc and/or custom scripts)

Tags: scripts, pandoc, workflow

I'm a fan of using things like pandoc, GPP and Rake to make my source files to look cleaner, be human readable, simplify my workflow and get some level of style/semantics separation (especially for larger projects). Yet, using these workflows I find I really miss having a live preview, like I did with latexian.

My ideal solution would work on OS X and linux, and be able to let me use vim as my editor (like http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/vim-live-latex-preview/ or https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown) but let me define a custom build script of some sort.

Failing that, even a viewer that would regen the pdf whenever I write a source file to disk would suffice. It needn't support things like syncing to where i'm currently editing (though it would be nice), as long as whenever the pdf is reloaded it won't change the current position it's looking it.

Failing even that, if someone could point me towards language bindings for a PDF Viewer or something similar so I can write my own script or app for this purpose I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Have you checked eclipse? There is also a live viewer with the option of syncing. More info can be found here:http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/ With eclipse whenever you save your document the pdf is generated.